# finding 6 numbers that are in a range with mean, mode and median averages

Tags: average

Can anybody tell me how to choose 6 numbers that have a range of 4, a median of 9, a mean of 9 and a mode of 7?

so far, i have 7,7,9,11

i know the mean should be 54/6 but the last 2 number must = 20, so 2 10's would negate the mode of 7

thanks

Comment: Does $7$ has to be the only mode? If not, I think the sequence $7,7,7,11,11,11$ works fine, since when there is no middle number, the median is the average of the *middle pair* of numbers.

Comment: yes the 7 has to be the only mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find $6$ integers with specific range, mean, median and mode. We call them $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6$ such that $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq x_4 \leq x_5 \leq x_6$ and then:

- range constraint: $x_6 - x_1 = 4$.
- median constraint: $\frac{x_3 + x_4}{2} = 9$.
- mean constraint: $\frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6}{6} = 9$.
- mode constraint: $x_2 = 7$, it comes from the fact that the number of $7$ is either $2$ or $3$. The $2$ if if you assume that all the other numbers are different. The $3$ comes from the fact that if you have more $7$ than that you violate the median constraint.

From all that you have that:
\begin{align}
&&\frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6}{6} &= 9 \\
&\Leftrightarrow& x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 &= 54 \\
\tag{Range constraint.} \\
&\Leftrightarrow& x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_1 + 4 &= 54 \\
&\Leftrightarrow& 2x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 &= 50 \\
\tag{Median constraint.} \\
&\Leftrightarrow& 2x_1 + x_2 + 18 + x_5 &= 50 \\
&\Leftrightarrow& 2x_1 + x_2 + x_5 &= 32 \\
\tag{Mode constraint.} \\
&\Leftrightarrow& 2x_1 + 7 + x_5 &= 32 \\
&\Leftrightarrow& 2x_1 + x_5 &= 25 \\
&\Leftrightarrow& x_1 &= \frac{25 - x_5}{2} \\
\end{align}
Now from the median constraint we have that $x_5 \geq 9$ and from the range constraint that $x_5 \leq 11$ and we have $3$ possibilities:

- $x_5 = 9$ which implies $x_1 = 8 > x_2$ which is a contradiction so it is not possible.
- $x_5 = 10$ which implies that $x_1$ is not an integer anymore so it is not possible.
- $x_5 = 11$ which implies that $x_1 = 7$. Thus we have $x_1 = 7$, $x_2 = 7$, $x_5 = 11$ and $x_6 = 11$. To respect the mode constraint we need to set $x_3 = 7$ but this implies that $x_4 = 11$ to respect the median constraint. However this solution violates the mode constraint once again.
  From the above we deduce that there is no $6$ integers satisfying all the constraints.

---

As mentioned in one of the comments if we relax the mode constraint to be non strict then $x_5 = 11$ becomes a viable solution and the following sets of numbers work:

- 7,7,7,11,11,11,
- 7,7,8,10,11,11,
- 7,7,9,9,11,11.

Comment: Thanks for as detailed answer. This was my niece's maths homework. I said to her that it couldn't be done and to confirm this with the teachers. Thought i were going mad after staring at it for 30 mins :)